# Android WebView Set Login Status to True after Successful Login

Tags: android, authentication, webview, sharedpreferences

I’m using Shared Preferences to store user data and set Login Status in a web view app for eCommerce Website. The user can either login via Login URL or at the Checkout Page. The issue I’m facing I can’t set Login status to “True” after the user successfully logged in so I can retrieve the username it keeps showing as "False".

EDIT: After posting the question I was able to find part of the solution for the Login URL to set the status to true however the CARTURL isn't working. I defined `isRedirected = true;` and set the condition to get the right status.

I'm reposting the code after edit:

```
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.e(TAG, "should override url loading" + url);
            view.loadUrl(url);

            isRedirected = true;
            return true;
        }

public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    //webView.setClickable(true);menuBtn.setClickable(true);cartImg.setClickable(true);logoImg.setClickable(true);
    Log.e(TAG, "on page finished" + url);
    Log.e(TAG, "is logged in==" + isLoggedin);
    isRedirected = true;
    String isLoggedin = "false";
    if(url.equals(Constants.ACCOUNTURL) && isRedirected && isLoggedin.equals("false")) {
        Log.e(TAG, "reload");
        //webView.loadUrl(Constants.ACCOUNTEDITURL);
        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Login", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putString("isLogedin", "true");
        editor.commit();
        setWelcome();
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You have signed in", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        toast.show();
    };

    if(url.equals(Constants.CARTURL) && isRedirected && isLoggedin.equals("false")) {
          Log.e(TAG, "Cart Login");
          //webView.loadUrl(Constants.ACCOUNTEDITURL);
          SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Login", MODE_PRIVATE);
          SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
          editor.putString("isLogedin", "true");
          editor.commit();
          setWelcome();
          Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You have signed in", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
          toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
          toast.show();
    };

    //if(url.equals(Constants.LOGOUTURL) && isLoggedin.equals("true")) {
    if(url.equals(Constants.LOGOUTURL)) {
        Log.e(TAG, "logging out-----------------");
        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Login", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putString("isLogedin", "false");
        //editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
        setWelcome();
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You have logged out", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        toast.show();
        //return;
    }

    if(isLoggedin.equals("true")) {
        Log.e(TAG, "in get name-----------------");
        mainView.addJavascriptInterface(new myJavaScriptInterface(), "CallToAnAndroidFunction");
        //String getnamejs = "(document.getElementById('input-firstname').value);";
        String getnamejs = "(document.getElementById('app_customer_name').innerHTML);";
        mainView.loadUrl("javascript: window.CallToAnAndroidFunction.getUserName" + getnamejs);
    }
```

Your help is highly appreciated, thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that the string variable isLoggedin is always false? could you mention where are you assigning the value for the variable isLoggedin.

Comment: Yes by default `private String isLoggedin = "false";` and it varies based on user action.

Comment: I see that in the shared preference the key for saving the login status is "isLogedin" which is different from the string variable "isLoggedin" with one 'g' is missing. Also, I see that there is no assignment for the String variable isLoggedin after user successful log in.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. the isLoggedin is a string while isLogedin is a TAG so I'm differentiating using the missing "g". Can you advise me with a code that can further help please

Comment: `isLoggedin = pref.getString("isLogedin", "");` how it's working

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code, I have modified the putString with boolean.

```
boolean isLoggedin;
SharedPreferences pref =
            getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Login", MODE_PRIVATE);

public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    Log.e(TAG, "should override url loading" + url);
    view.loadUrl(url);

    isRedirected = true;
    return true;
}

public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

    Log.e(TAG, "on page finished" + url);

    isLoggedin = pref.getBoolean(“isLoggedin”, false);

    if (url.equals(Constants.ACCOUNTURL) && url.equals(Constants.CARTURL) && !isLoggedin) {
        Log.e(TAG, "reload");
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

        editor.putBoolean(“isLoggedin", true);
                editor.commit();
        setWelcome();

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You have signed in", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        toast.show();

        Log.e(TAG, "in get name-----------------");
        mainView.addJavascriptInterface(new myJavaScriptInterface(), "CallToAnAndroidFunction");
        //String getnamejs = "(document.getElementById('input-firstname').value);";
        String getnamejs = "(document.getElementById('app_customer_name')[0].innerHTML);";
        mainView.loadUrl("javascript: window.CallToAnAndroidFunction.getUserName" + getnamejs);
    }
    //if(url.equals(Constants.LOGOUTURL) && isLoggedin) {
    if (url.equals(Constants.LOGOUTURL)) {
        Log.e(TAG, "logging out-----------------");

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("isLoggedin", false);
        //editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
        setWelcome();

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You have logged out", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        toast.show();
        //return;
    }
```

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: Hi thanks for the code and support, I had to workaround the code to reach a solution as setting boolean instead of string for isLoggedIn will cause issues on the other parts of the code where they're working fine.I've edited my question and was able to resolve part of the issue however in CartURL it keeps showing as signed-in even if I am not signed-in any possible solution please?